# WPF DataGrid Customizing both RowStyle and CellStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to set up a DataGrid, with the following design constraints based on my DataContext bindings:

(The Grid itself is 4 columns: 3 DataGridTextColumns and one DataGridTemplateColumn using a MahApps Metro Toggle Switch as the control)

- DEFAULT: Text Column is Center Text Aligned, Font Size 15.
- If IsMasked is true, then the entire row's foreground should be light grey, and every Text Column's FontStyle should be oblique. All other cases have the assertion that IsMasked is false. (This is to effectively give the row a disabled look while still ensuring the Toggle Switch is still enabled.)
- If IsFull is true, the row's background should be red.
- If Is98PercentFull is True, then the background should be orange.
- If Is95PercentFull is True, then the background should be gold.

The current troubles I'm running into right now is that the grid appears to behave exactly as I intend in design view, but during debugging, whenever IsMasked is set to true, the only thing that changes is the background color going to default. I do not get the light grey foreground and oblique text. Also, all of my TextBlocks lose their default styling, so they appear as size ~10 and in the top left corner of the text block.

How can I effectively set up a DataGridRowStyle that also properly manages the various designs it can have, based on the content of that row's cells?

```
<Style x:Key="CellTextBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMasked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Oblique" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="RowStyle"
                       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}"
                       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Is95PercentFull, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMasked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>

                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Is98PercentFull, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMasked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>

                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFull, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMasked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </MultiDataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
```

EDIT: For some reason, if I have RowVirtualization enabled, the DataGrid becomes even buggier, with only applying styles properly upon scrolling upward.

Edit 2: Anyone?

Comment: what happens if you don't use your RowStyle only ?

Comment: No styling whatsoever happens.